# ansible не видит ansible_default_ipv4

Tags: сеть, администрирование, ip, ansible

Тестовый вызов с моей рабочей машины.

```
ansible -i ./hosts-adminvps -m debug -a "var=ansible_default_ipv4" -b lb 

lb2.****.ru | SUCCESS => {
"ansible_default_ipv4": "VARIABLE IS NOT DEFINED!"
}
```

В интернетах пишут, что проблема может быть в дефолтном маршруте.
На lb2:

```
route -n
Таблица маршутизации ядра протокола IP
Destination Gateway Genmask Flags Metric Ref Use Iface
0.0.0.0 ***.***.165.1 0.0.0.0 UG 0 0 0 eth0
***.***.165.0 0.0.0.0 255.255.255.0 U 0 0 0 eth0
```

Также на сервере если вызвать:

```
ansible all -i localhost, -m setup -c local

...
"ansible_default_ipv4": {
"address": "***.***.165.185",
"alias": "eth0",
"broadcast": "***.***.165.255",
"gateway": "***.***.165.1",
"interface": "eth0",
"macaddress": "**:**:**:**:**:**",
"mtu": 1500,
"netmask": "255.255.255.0",
"network": "***.***.165.0",
"type": "ether"
},
```

Answer (score 1):

Как я понимаю debug не собирает факты с хостов.

> ansible -m setup -a "filter=ansible_default_ipv4" -u root  test

Comment: факты нормально получались, ошибка в другом, в роли я проходил по всем хостам циклом в jinja шаблоне, но при вызове плейбука делал фильтр по хосту. В итоге он пытался получить доступ к переменной фактов которая не была запрошена тк хост был отфильтрован.

Comment: правильнее было проверить наличие фактов так
ansible -i ./hosts-adminvps db --private-key ~/.ssh/id_rsa -u root -m setup | grep -A 2 ansible_default_ipv4